# Javascript [Prototype/Scriptaculous] - create an infinite unidirectional slideshow

Tags: javascript, slideshow, infinite

let's say you've got a slideshow like this (I omit here the 'previous' and 'next' buttons):

```
<div id="slides">
   <article id="slide1" class="slide">[...]</article>
   <article id="slide2" class="slide">[...]</article>
   <article id="slide3" class="slide">[...]</article>
</div>
```

There are 3 slides here, but that is totally dynamic.
My big issue is not so to create an infinite slideshow, but to create one which transitions from one slide to the other **always in the same way**.

If we consider this cycle:

```
slide 1 -> slide 2 -> slide 3 -> slide 1 -> slide 2 -> slide 3 -> slide 1 -> ...
```

What I want is the impression we always slide to the left (**even when we get back from slide 3 to slide 1!!**).

If you have any ideas, please tell me, I have already tried many things.

Thanks in advance, 
Rolf

P.S.: I'm using Prototype v1.6 and Scriptaculous v1.9.0

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to work the slideshow, you want to utilise the modulus function to give you that infinite loopyness.

So if you have a variable id which is the one which is meant to go 1->2->3 and then back around, you would need to update it so it goes back from 3 to 1, as such:

```
id=(id+2)%4-1
```

That'll give you the 1->2->3->1->2->3... effect

That little formula may look slightly confusing because you're going from 1 to 3 rather than 0 to 2. If you were to start at 0 the simplified formula would be:

```
id=(id+1)%3
```

You just need to adapt the 3 on the end to the number of slides the slideshow as, or in the top example, the number of slides+1.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. That solves the infinite part. However, my issue is with the transition impression. Transitions like from 1 to 2, or 2 to 3 should "go" to the same direction than the transition from 3 to 1 (usually, it just rewinds, taking the opposite direction and this is what I wanna avoid).

Comment: Unfortunately I've never used Prototype or Scriptaculous so I can't give you much advice with that :(